# Coefficients of a cosine series

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Let $u$ have the cosine series representation
$$u = \sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty} a_\underline{k} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k_1 x }{L_1}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k_2 y }{L_2}\right) $$

What are the coefficients $A_{\underline{k}}$ in
$$u^2 = \sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty} A_{\underline{k}} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k_1 x }{L_1}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k_2 y }{L_2}\right) $$
in terms of the $a_\underline{k}$?

Thanks :)

Comment: What are the $\underline k$ ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust, surely the pair $(k_1,k_2)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yep $\underline{k} = (k_1,k_2)$

Comment: $(a\cos(t)+b\cos(2t))^2=a^2\cos^2(t)+2ab\cos(t)\cos(2t)+b^2\cos^2(2t)$. You can linearize the products/squares by means of trigonometric identities, but you'll get half-integer $t$. I wonder if your question has a solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well I have basically taken a doubly periodic function $u$ which is even in both $x$ and $y$. Assuming (the correct regularity), it is ok to write this as a Fourier cosine series. Then $u^2$ will also be even in $x$ and $y$ and we can write it as a cosine series. Your claim is that we may introduce frequencies that have period equal to twice the domain size, which is impossible.

Comment: My bad, I took the formulas in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

In $1D$,

$$\left(\sum a_k\cos(kt)\right)^2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_k a_j\cos(kt)\cos(jt)\\
=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_ka_j\left(\cos((k-j)t)+\cos((k+j)t)\right)\\
=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=k}^{-\infty} a_ka_{k-j}\cos(kt)+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=k}^\infty a_ka_{j-k}\cos(kt)$$

so that

$$A_k=\sum_{j=k}^{-\infty} a_ka_{k-j}+\sum_{j=k}^\infty a_ka_{j-k}=\frac12 a_{k}^2+\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_ka_{j}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \cos mx \cos nx = \frac{\cos (m+n)x+\cos (m-n)x}{2}$

$\displaystyle 4A_{ij}=
\sum_{m-n=i}\sum_{p-q=j} a_{mn} \, a_{pq}+
\sum_{m+n=i}\sum_{p-q=j} a_{mn} \, a_{pq}+
\sum_{m-n=i}\sum_{p+q=j} a_{mn} \, a_{pq}+
\sum_{m+n=i}\sum_{p+q=j} a_{mn} \, a_{pq}$